# Why CSV only write last data with floating data?

Tags: python, csv, computer-vision

i am extracting data from camera, the data is live. However, whenever i write CSV files, it only write the last data before I close the camera. Below are the codes

```
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    id, conf = rec.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])

    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    #print (conf)
    if conf <= 55:
        id = id 
        counter = counter + 1
        t = (stop - start)/cv2.getTickFrequency();
        print(t)
        print (counter)

        results = []
        with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
            #row[0] = counter
            #row[1:] = t
            results.append([counter, t])
            for result in results:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows([results])
else:
        id="unknown"
```

Please help me guys. Been suffering for this quite awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file for writing `with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:` in every loop. This overwrites your data each time. You should move this to the top and outside of your `for` loop, so you open the file once. I'd also move your writer definition `writer = csv.writer(f)` outside the `for` loop, but inside the `open`.

Another, less appealing option is to change the `open` to `append` mode, so it won't overwrite each time: `with open('mycsv.csv', 'a', newline='')`. Note the `'a'` mode instead of `'w'`.

Comment: Hi Sam, I tried to put the `with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as f: ` before <for (x, y, w, h) in faces:> while other remains unchange. It gives a blank CSV file

Comment: Did you indent the `for` loop and all the following code under the `with open()`? If you don't, it will just open and close the output file immediately. Can you update or add to show your new code? Also, make sure you are looking at the right output file, check the timestamp to make sure it is updating.

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote and select the answer as correct :)  have a great day.